# python pandas how to copy duplicate value to new Column and keep the first duplicate value empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an dataframe like this

```
  sku
FAT-001
FAT-001
FAT-001
FAT-002
FAT-002
```

I want to create another column depend on the duplicate sku value. The first duplicate value must me empty in dup-sku column. **I want to keep only duplicate sku in my dup-sku column.** So my expected dataframe will be look like this:

```
  sku        dup-sku
FAT-001      #empty 
FAT-001      FAT-001
FAT-001      FAT-001
FAT-002      #emty  
FAT-002      FAT-002
FAT-003
```

The first value of duplicate in dup-sku column must be empty

Comment: sorry Sir. My mistake. FAT-003 will not be in dup-sku column as it's not duplicate value. Actually here I am meaning empty row by using '#empty'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for your example ?

```
df['dup']=df['sku']
df['dup'].loc[~df['sku'].duplicated(keep='first')]=''
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. what this sign meaning here `~` ? can you please explain little bit your code so I can understand how it's working. Normally `duplicated(keep='first')` mean it will drop all duplicate except only first one.

Comment: Yes. So df['sku'].duplicated(keep='first') will return a series of boolean with first duplicate as False and rest of the duplicates as True. The ~ in front of the series will inverse all booleans, so now the first duplicate will be True and rest of the duplicates will be False now.So we target those with .loc to set these values to being empty...hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

another approach for the given example:

```
df['dup-sku'] = df.where(df==df.shift(),'')

>>> df
'''
       sku  dup-sku
0  FAT-001         
1  FAT-001  FAT-001
2  FAT-001  FAT-001
3  FAT-002         
4  FAT-002  FAT-002
5  FAT-003
```